# VBA: Make copy of workbook, remove shets and then save it with different name?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do the following:

- Copy a workbook
- Remove some of the sheets
- Save it as a different file name

This was my attempt but its not working:

```
Private Sub publish()
    Dim new_wb As Workbook

    'Doesnt seem to compile??
    Set new_wb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy

    For i = new_wb.Sheets.Count To 1
        If InStr(LCase(new_wb.Sheets(i).CodeName), "output") = 0 Then
            new_wb.Sheets(i).Delete
        End If
        i = i - 1
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    new_wb.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Range("output_path").Value
    new_wb.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Could someone please help me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Improve as follows according to comments within the code below:

```
Private Sub publish()
    Dim new_wb As Workbook

    'let's separate your solution into two lines
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy
    Set new_wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim i as integer

    'add this to make sheets deletion silently
    Application.DisplayAlerts = false

    'add step -1 at the end of this
    For i = new_wb.Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(LCase(new_wb.Sheets(i).CodeName), "Arkusz1") = 0 Then
            new_wb.Sheets(i).Delete
        End If
        'this is not required any more:
        'i = i - 1
    Next

    'set back alerts to true which is a good habit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = true

    'rest unchanged
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'here you could have an error if 'output_path' doesn't exist in new workbook
    new_wb.SaveCopyAs Filename:=Range("output_path").Value
    new_wb.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```